# Circular track - finding distances between the bus stops.

Tags: recreational-mathematics

[image]

Tried different combinations with simultaneous equations, but could not get the answer. Any easier way to get the answer.

this is my workout.
[image]

Comment: Your picture is very useful, you know $a+b$, $c+d$, $b+c$ and you need $a+d$, which is (from picture) $a+b + c + d - (b+c)$.

Comment: Hi Atbey, I worked out with your logic but unable to get the whole a+b+c+d.. Can you please elaborate on this one.

Comment: Your history shows that you tend not to award points to people here that answer your questions. People here like getting acknowledgement for answering questions. If you don't reciprocate, why should they?

Comment: @Jens, This is not fair, Plese check fairly before pointing out to anyone. I always gave Answer upvote/comment upvote if I find the answer/comment is correct, might be you are looking that I should upvote all the Answers and Comments and sorry that won't happens with anyone.